# Mavericks install icon

Tags: install, macos, icon

Just back from Apple after they reloaded the entire system off my time machine backup due to "hard drive damaged" message and lock up during Mavericks install.  The hard drive was fine, by the way.  Everything seems fine now, except that I have the "Install OSX Mavericks" icon sitting in my dock and also, of course, on the application list on the finder.  I assume this icon can be trashed? I don't want to delete something that may be needed in the future.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can delete that safely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely delete that, unless you wish to use it to write a bootable USB thumb drive *(this relies on that linking to the full installer)*.